# How to make an existing chart dynamic

Tags: excel

I have already made charts and would like to make it dynamic so that when I add new data (highlighted yellow) the charts will update automatically.

Can someone guide me on how to do this.

Image of sample data for what I am trying to do is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would advise the use of named formulas for your series data inputs. Your named formulas can be dynamic in nature, in that they search across the row and check for the first blank row of data.

As an example, all the grapsh can have their horizontal axis labels set to the named formula 'validDates', where

validDates is put in the name manager as :

```
='NTesco'!$C$2:INDEX('NTesco'!$2:$2, MIN(IF('NTesco'!$B$3:$AZZ$3="", COLUMN('NTesco'!$B$3:$AZZ$3), 99999)))
```

N.B. You could use slightly different variations for each graphs date range if there will be independent data gathering for each corresponding value range. Then you should use that row's row index in the IF logical test argument...

You could also use a formula for the first graph values, such as:

```
='NTesco'!$C$3:INDEX('NTesco'!$3:$3, MIN(IF('NTesco'!$B$3:$AZZ$3="", COLUMN('NTesco'!$B$3:$AZZ$3), 99999)))
```

The AIOWHB graph takes values from the 4th row, so would be:

```
='NTesco'!$C$4:INDEX('NTesco'!$4:$4, MIN(IF('NTesco'!$B$4:$AZZ$4="", COLUMN('NTesco'!$B$4:$AZZ$4), 99999)))
```

And so on for the other two....